# Why does an error 'unexpected WSL error" always appear when I run docker desktop?

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hyper-v

The error is like: [image: 1]

And there is always a problem with my wsl:
When I run

```
wsl --set-version Ubuntu-22.04 2
```

the error message is like:

```
"Your current computer configuration does not support WSL 2. Please enable the 'Virtual Machine Platform' optional component and ensure that virtualization is enabled in BIOS. For more information, visit https://aka.ms/enablevirtualization. Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateVm/0x80370102"
```

My os edition is windows 11 home and I didn't find hyper-v in my system, so I run a script to install it.

```
pushd "%~dp0"
dir /b %SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\*Hyper-V*.mum >hyper-v.txt
for /f %%i in ('findstr /i . hyper-v.txt 2^>nul') do dism /online /norestart /add-package:"%SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\%%i"
del hyper-v.txt
Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Hyper-V-All /LimitAccess /ALL
```

And I have checked the virtualization using task manager that the vt bios is running. I have run

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart
```

and

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart
```

and reboot computer before set-version to 2. It just doesn't work. So is this problem related to my docker error and how can I solve them?